# Communication between Arduino and Can Bus

Tags: spi, can-bus

Function `mcp2515_get_message` appears the following instruction:

```
 uint32_t i1 = (uint32_t) spi_putc(0xff),
          i2 = (uint32_t) spi_putc(0xff),
          i3 = (uint32_t) spi_putc(0xff),
          i4 = (uint32_t) spi_putc(0xff);
```

This instruction is used to fetch data used for determining the message id. Supposing the 32 bit source data contains 
Hex `0xAA3A6060`, which values will appear in `i1, i2, i3, i4`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the "32 bit source" big or little endian?

Comment: Is this a school assigment?